# Algorithms for a "Travelling Salesman with radius / time limit"?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I can't talk about my real-world situation I need this for, but imagine you walk around a warehouse that has things with RFID tags scattered around in it, and you have ten minutes to get within 2m of as many tags as possible. Thus unlike a Travelling Salesman, who needs to hit exact targets, I only need to be within a certain radius.

Another example would be the game agar.io, where you control a big blob and need to pick up as many little blobs as possible (defined as "their center is within your radius").

Unlike a Travelling Salesman, I don't want to -visit-every-city- pick up every item. Just as many as possible within a given time (i.e. length of travelled distance; I can ignore acceleration for the moment).

A reasonable approximation might be to start with r=0, i.e. find a route of at most length N which starts at a given point (the door of the warehouse) and touches as many points as possible, and then improve that (by "cutting corners").

Comment: I'm assuming by "radius" you mean the Euclidean distance?

Comment: Of course. The examples say as much.

Answer (score 0):

Let the parts have coordinates $(p_{ix},p_{iy})$ for $i=1,\ldots n$, $r$ the maximum distance from the starting location to a part, and $(x_0,y_0)$ be the starting location. We want to choose a sequence of points $(z_{jx},z_{jy})$, $1\leqslant j\leqslant n$ that maximizes the number of parts covered (if $k<n$ moves are used, set $(z_{lx},z_{ly})=(z_{kx},z_{ky}$ for $k< l\leqslant n$. Set $(z_{0x},z_{0y})$ for convenience. Let
$$
w_{ij} =\begin{cases}
1,& \text{if move } j \text{ covers part } i\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then we can model this problem by an integer quadratically constrained program:

\begin{align}
\max&\quad \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij}\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{(z_{jx}-z_{j-1,x})^2 + (z_{jy}-z_{j-1,y})^2}\leqslant D\\
&\quad w_{ij}\leqslant \left(\frac{z_{jx}-p_{ix}}R\right)^2 + \left(\frac{z_{jy}-p_{iy}}R\right)^2\quad \forall\ i,j\\
&\quad \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij} \leqslant 1\quad \forall\ i\\
&\quad w_{ij}\in\{0,1\}\quad \forall i,j
\end{align}

Comment: You seem to propose finding a single (x,y) so that the most points are within r. That is not what I need. I need to choose an arbitrary number of (xi,yi) so that the sum of distances between subsequent points is at most D, maximizing the number of (pix,piy) whose distance from one of these segments is at most R. What I have is (x0,y0), which is my starting point (in my examples: entrance of warehouse; center of the screen).

Comment: Ah, I interpreted the question differently. I'll come up with a new model then.